# d3.js - Truncate node text for specified node d.type

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to truncate node text/label for specified nodes based on the node d.type (or d.data.type depending on d3.js version).

So for general truncating I have used:

```
if (d.name.length > 60)
    return d.name.substring(0, 30) + '...';
else
    return d.name;
```

But how do I do this for specific d.type (or d.data.type) nodes?

For example, `if d.data.type == 'unit1'` then truncate label

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq1x8eL5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extending your condition?

```js
if (d.name.length > 60 && d.data.type == 'unit1')
    return d.name.substring(0, 30) + '...';
else
    return d.name;
```

But your data don't have the `type` for every node, only the leafs. Maybe this is your problem.